# How to boot androidx86 in gui?

Tags: android, linux, virtualbox, driver

After installing androidx86 on VirtualBox at boot android boot in CLI and after a couple of seconds  I got a black screen, with a blinking underscore at the top-left of the screen, its keep blinking without any change, it wont boot the gui.

I have tried different installations following various guides on internet, but  I got ever the same problem, I have also tried with Alt+f7  key combo and putting nomodoeset in boot option in grub, but nothing.

In all tutorial I have found online they always start the gui without any problem. But I got always the black screen after 2 seconds of cli.

Comment: I forgot to say that I have already tryed with 3d aceleration

Answer (score 6):

[Found a fix posted by Val at superuser.com:](https://superuser.com/questions/1395714/dont-boot-in-gui-but-just-in-command-line)

> I managed to solved my problem :
>
> I just **changed the display option Graphics Controller to VBoxVGA and enabled 3D animation**.

Comment: did this solved your problem? if yes could you please mark this as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on the virtual machine you are looking to modify, and hit `Settings`
2. Navigate to `Display`, then make sure you are on the `Screen` tab
3. Set `Monitor Count` to `2` or more
4. Set the `Graphics Controller` to `VBoxVGA`
5. Increase the `Video Memory` to `128MB` (choose the maximum amount available to you)

[image: Display Settings]